# facebook login by activity 1 and send post to fb wall by activity 2

Tags: java, android, facebook

i am making an android app which is using Facebook to post status to wall.Integration part is done.I am using Facebook sdk 3.0.

My UI is **Tab layout**:1st Tab is Home.2nd Tab is settings.(two activities)

Firstly in 2nd tab, i have Facebook Login Button,through which i log in and log out.(same button)

Then in 1st tab,I have postButton,though which i post a status to facebook profile.

I have checked lots of tutorials.But i am not getting any answers related to this.Morevoer all tutorials are having all the workings in single activity,which i don't want.

Please can anyone help with my scenario. **Login in one activity and send post to fb wall by second activity**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier under Facebook 3.0 since you have the Session object.
You can call the static `Session.getActiveSession()` in any activity, then you should make sure the session is open and ready with the required permissions (easily achieved) and publish whatever you want (or open the session and/or request publish permissions).

Comment: this is what i am doing when there is one activity.chk this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332122/working-with-facebook-sdk-and-using-two-activities-core-java

Comment: Make sure you call Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(...) in your second activity as well...